# React Native unable to resolve module/appentry

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I have this issue when they to start iOS project. Can someone help me how to fix it. I already deleted node modules and re installed them. It happens when I start IOS simulator and it shows red screen. I am new to react native and try to solve this issues several days already. Thank you everyone for answers!

Here is what I see on red screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkqoI.png)

**Here is my JSON:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSU15.png)
`

Reinstall expo and node modules
updated MAC OS version

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the error message and JSON as text and not an image. Have you tried running `expo doctor` in your project?